# Calculating values in a dataframe based on another column in lagged row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `gdp` for which I currently have the percentile GDP changes. I'm trying to compute the "raw" GDP figures for each `date`, for each `sim_num`.

```
gdp

   date        sim_num     gdp_change 
1  2022-12-31  1           1.1958271
2  2023-03-31  1           1.2992509 
3  2023-06-30  1           1.8514085 
4  2023-09-30  1           -0.765459 
5  2023-12-31  1           1.1555216 
6  2022-12-31  2           0.1667283
7  2023-03-31  2           -0.846561 
8  2023-06-30  2           0.1479246
9  2023-09-30  2           -0.303339 
10 2023-12-31  2           0.1883053
```

I know the raw GDP figures for 2022-12-31 already, which is 555690000000. So I start a new column `raw_gdp`, adding this number into 2022-12-31 for each sim.

```
gdp$raw_gdp = 0
gdp[gdp$date == as.Date("2022-12-31"),]$raw_gdp <- 555690000000

   date        sim_num     gdp_change   raw_gdp
1  2022-12-31  1           1.1958271    555690000000
2  2023-03-31  1           1.2992509    0
3  2023-06-30  1           1.8514085    0
4  2023-09-30  1           -0.765459    0
5  2023-12-31  1           1.1555216    0
6  2022-12-31  2           0.1667283    555690000000
7  2023-03-31  2           -0.846561    0
8  2023-06-30  2           0.1479246    0
9  2023-09-30  2           -0.303339    0
10 2023-12-31  2           0.1883053    0
```

**How can I calculate `raw_gdp` figures for the zeros?**

So for row 2 I will need 555690000000 * (1+ 1.2992509 / 100) = 562909807326.

And for row 3: 562909807326 * (1+ 1.8514085 / 100) = 573331567346.

Row 6 remains unchanged.

Row 7 will be 555690000000 * (1+ -0.846561 / 100) = 550985745179.

Code to replicate dataframe:

```
gdp <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2022-12-31","2023-03-31","2023-06-30", "2023-09-30","2023-12-31")), sim_num = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), gdp_change = c(1.1958271, 1.2992509, 1.8514085, -0.765459,  1.1555216, 0.1667283, -0.846561, 0.1479246, -0.303339, 0.1883053))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cumprod` is what you'll be after to calculate the cumulative product of the GDP change, from there the initial amount can be multiplied by the cumulative GDP change.

```
init <- 555690000000
gdp %>% 
  mutate(gdp_absolute = (1+ gdp_change/100),
         cum_gdp_absolute = cumprod(gdp_absolute),
         GDP = case_when(date == as.Date("2022-12-31") ~ init,
                         T ~ (init*cum_gdp_absolute)))
```